# Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence for twisted K-theory for infinite-dimensional CW-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, k-theory, spectral-sequences

I'm writing a thesis that runs an AHSS for twisted K-theory over an Eilenberg-MacLane space, namely an infinite-dimensional CW-complex.

In Atiyahs works *[Twisted K-Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407054v2)* and [*Twisted K-Theory and cohomology*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510674), I could not find any reference on how the twisted AHSS would behave for infinite-dimensional CW-complexes. Neither could I find any reference in his foundational work [*Vector bundles and homogeneous spaces*](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789814401319_0008), where Atiyah introduces the *untwisted* version of the AHSS.
Is there any published material defining a twisted AHSS infinite-dimensional CW-complex? I do not need convergence of the sequence (that might be affected), only that the calculations of the successive pages work.

I've also tried theorem 15.7. of [Switzers *Algebraic Topology*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-61923-6), but this theorem gives the sequence for generalized homology theories, not generalized cohomology theories, such as twisted K-Theory. At the moment, I'm trying to extract the information from [Whitehead's *Elements of Homotopy Theory*](https://www.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-6318-0), Theorem 3.6 of chapter XIII, but not with too much success.

Comment: Atiyah-Segal's description of the spectral sequence in the papers you cite should work also for infinite-dimensional complexes.

Comment: @JHF I think so too, but for my thesis I need to present a proper source for this, and proving it is out of the scope for the thesis.